# Is there a way out of being stuck in base in Siege Mode as Derpl?

Tags: awesomenauts

I teleported back to base in Siege mode as Derpl and now I'm stuck there due to "E" being both the shop key and Siege mode deactivation. Is there any way to transform back into Walker mode other than the hotkey?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any way to change back other than hotkeys but you can go into the menu and under "controls" add another hotkey to toggle Siege mode. One can also change the shop key to something else as well. This works even in mid-match.

Comment: Isn't scroll button click an alternative, for Ability 2, by default?

Comment: Right click is the same ability as set to "Q" but there isn't any mouse button mapped to "E" by default. It's likely due to my being on a Mac at the moment.

Comment: In Linux, you can generally click l&r mouse at the same time to emulate a middle-click (or scroll-wheel-click), which as Luck said, is mapped to E by default.   (No idea if that works in OSX)   (Should have mentioned OSX in your question ...)   Why haven't you accepted your own answer, and closed this?